# Automatically updating known_hosts file when host key changes using Paramiko

Tags: python, ssh, key, paramiko, ssh-keys

Currently I am using Paramiko (in Python) to execute remote command on a node. At times, remote nodes change theirs public key, and consequently Paramiko fails as fingerprints do not match. Is there a way to update the keys in `known_hosts` file when they change? If this is not possible is there any other way to ignore the warning thrown?

Currently I have a hacky solution where `known_hosts` file is deleted before making the call which is not good.

Answer (score 12):

`BadHostKeyException` is thrown when a host key changes, as that is a sign of the connecting being hijacked (aka [Man-in-the-middle attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack)).

You should never blindly ignore the exception. Unless maybe, if you connect to a server located in the same private network as your client.

In your specific case, a better strategy is to preserve host keys during server reinstall.

---

Anyway, if you really *do not care about security*, and are willing to blindly accept any host key:

- do not call [`SSHClient.load_host_keys`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/client.html#paramiko.client.SSHClient.load_host_keys), so that you start with a blank list of known host keys;
- and use [`AutoAddPolicy`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/client.html#paramiko.client.AutoAddPolicy), to automatically accept host keys of new hosts (all hosts are new due to the previous point):

  ```
  ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
  ```